# Chromatic index of cartesian product of a graph with a class one graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How is it that the chromatic index of any graph $G$ composed with a cartesian product with a class one graph $H$, that is a graph with chromatic index equal to its maximum degree, always equal to its maximum degree, that is how is $\chi'(G\square H)=\Delta(G\square H)$ where $\Delta$ be the maximum degree?

I know that $\chi'(G\square K_2)=\Delta(G\square K_2)$, as the one missing color of any instance of $G$ in $G\square K_2$ in any $\Delta+1$ coloring of $G$ can be given to the instance of $K_2$ joining the other instance, but how is the above result true? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @bof thanks! edited the post

Comment: Can you kindly share the proof of $\chi'(G\square K_2) = \Delta(G\square K_2)$?

Comment: @S.Marco I think it is straightforward. I have just explained the 'proof' in the post itself- "as the one missing color of any instance of $G$ in $G\square K_2$ in any $\Delta+1$ coloring of $G$ can be given to the instance of $K_2$ joining the other instance"

Comment: I am beginning Graph Theory. So if a color is missing in one copy then, you form an edge with another copy and assign it some color say $k$ is that true?

Comment: @S.Marco yes, the missed color is given to the lone edge joining the other copy of $G$

Comment: Then how do you arrive to the conclusion?

Comment: @S.Marco since the degree increases by one while forming the cartesian product, the conclusion is immediate. If you still have doubt, you could ask at math.SE

Comment: That’s the link?

Comment: @S.Marco Hello, MathOverflow is for research type questions  (or problems that are not immediate for graduate level students). If you have basic and intermediate type questions, you should try http://math.stackexchange.com (abbreviated as math.SE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your generalization from the $G \square K_2$ case is the right idea: Whenever a vertex $u \in G$ is missing a color at one of its edges (say the color $i$), it's missing the *same* color in the other copy of $G$ (in the $G \square K_2$ case) and hence that edge formed by the Cartesian product with $K_2$ may be colored by $i$ without creating a conflict. A similar technique works in the more general case. First, let's see what we're aiming for for $\chi'(G \square H)$:

Note that for a vertex $(u, v) \in G \square H$, we have $deg_{G \square H}(u, v) = deg_{G}(u) + deg_{H}(v)$. Hence by picking $u \in G, v \in H$ each of maximum degree, we see that $\Delta(G \square H) = \Delta(G) + \Delta(H)$. Our job is therefore to construct a proper $(\Delta(G) + \Delta(H))$-edge-coloring of $G \square H$.

For each copy of $G$ in $G \square H$, use an identical $\Delta(G) + 1$-coloring (which exists by Vizing's theorem (as you mentioned in the proof of $\chi'(G\square K_2)=\Delta(G\square K_2)$)). With $\Delta(G) + 1$ colors allowed, some color $i$ is missing from all edges incident to all copies of the vertex $u \in V(G)$ (for any $u$). To color the copy of $H$ whose first coordinates are all $u$, we need only $\Delta(H)$ colors (since $H$ is class 1); we choose to use $i$ along with $\Delta(H) - 1$ additional colors. Doing this for each $u \in G$ yields an edge-coloring of $G \square H$ in $(\Delta(G) + 1) + (\Delta(H) - 1) = \Delta(G) + \Delta(H)$ colors, as needed; this completes the proof.

**Remark:** I see that you're an experienced user, so I skimped on the details a bit. Let me know if anything needs more filling in.

Comment: Can you please explain the case of $\chi'(G\square K_2) = \Delta(G\square K_2)$?

Comment: It's the same argument written, just replace $H$ with $K_2$ and $\Delta(H)$ with $\Delta(K_2) = 1$. This answer is a generalization of the problem to class 1 graphs, but since $K_2$ is of class 1 (just color the single edge with one color), the theorem applies to $K_2$ as well.